# creating classes based on Object.class

Tags: java

I want to define a list of classes and instantiate them later. I have a list like this

```
List<Class> classList = new ArrayList<>();
classList.add(ClassA.class);
classList.add(ClassB.class);
```

I want to read from this list and create the classes. I don't know witch classes I have to create since clients of my library will define this list. All i know is all of this classes extend from the same class and have one object as constructor argument. 

Any idea how should i achieve this?

Comment: Use `List<? extends YourSuperClass>`

Comment: You want to create new  _instances_, right? One instance per element of your list?

Comment: @ΔλЛ that require clients to create classes! Due to performance issues i don't want clients to initialize anything, I just want them to define them so I can later on decide when to create the objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If constructors of all your classes in question accept a single parameter, and the type of that parameter is the same (let's say it's `String`), you could instantiate such a class with the following:

```
Object instance = clazz.getConstructor(String.class).newInstance("string value you pass to the constructor");
```

Also, if all your classes extend class `Super`, it's better to write `Class<? extends Super>` instead of raw `Class`. Then you could write

```
Super instance = clazz.getConstructor(String.class).newInstance("string value you pass to the constructor");
```